# Maven build error: Failed to execute goal, missing a class

Tags: eclipse, maven, vaadin

I'm trying to package the sample application from vaadin 7.0.0 with the maven plugin for eclipse, but every time a run the goal "package", building fails with the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project essai: Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile: org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/util/scan/InclusionScanException
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/Benoit/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.3.2/maven-compiler-plugin-2.3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/Benoit/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
```

The result of mvn package -X is here: http://pastebin.com/jk5uW8Ut

My pom.xml is the following:
    
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.mycompany
    essai
    war
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    Vaadin Web Application

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <vaadin.version>7.0.0.rc2</vaadin.version>
    <vaadin.plugin.version>${vaadin.version}</vaadin.plugin.version>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
        <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- As we are doing "inplace" GWT compilation, ensure the widgetset -->
        <!-- directory is cleaned properly -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</directory>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                <!-- <runTarget>mobilemail</runTarget> -->
                <!-- We are doing "inplace" but into subdir VAADIN/widgetsets. This 
                    way compatible with Vaadin eclipse plugin. -->
                <webappDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets
                </webappDirectory>
                <hostedWebapp>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets
                </hostedWebapp>
                <noServer>true</noServer>
                <!-- Remove draftCompile when project is ready -->
                <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
                <compileReport>true</compileReport>
                <style>OBF</style>
                <strict>true</strict>
                <runTarget>http://localhost:8080/</runTarget>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- if you don't specify any modules, the plugin will find them -->
                        <!-- <modules>     <module>com.vaadin.demo.mobilemail.gwt.ColorPickerWidgetSet</module> 
                            </modules> -->
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                        <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        vaadin-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [7.0.0.rc2,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>resources</goal>
                                        <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
</project>
```

I'm new to maven and even if I found many post about this error, I haven't been able to understand what could cause this error.

Comment: Please attach output of execution with `-X` command line option.

Comment: it's here http://pastebin.com/jk5uW8Ut (couldn't paste it in the post)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here seems to be the problem:

> [FATAL] Non-parseable POM C:\Users\Benoit.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-parent\16\maven-parent-16.pom

Because of this error maven was unable to add to plugin's classpath all the necessary libraries.

I recommend you to remove everything under `C:\Users\Benoit\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\` and rebuild the project. This should help.

Comment: I did not have the same FATAL error, but still helped me solved the problem by removing everything under ~/.m2 except settings.xml. Thanks!

Comment: i didn't solve even i removed all under repository folder.